# Accessing Windows PC folder on Android tablets without internet connection

Tags: wi-fi, windows, remote-access

I am trying to access a Windows PC folder on my Android tablets (let's say 10 tablets). I have a video folder in my PC and I want to access that folder and play video. Things I have tried are:

- Using JCIFS library and Samba server: the drawback is it requires internet connection.
- Using WAMP server and localhost: this solution was perfect until I tested it on multiple devices. It takes a lot of time to buffer big video files and sometimes fails to access videos.

Is there any other method to do that without root? Any other methods to connect my Android tablets to Windows PC and access the video files from a folder?

Comment: "*It takes a lot of time to buffer big video files and sometimes fails to access videos*" -- I would only assume that you tried to buffer those files from those devices on a Wi-Fi. Don't be surprised, well. Wi-Fi has its limitations and so as the hardware providing the Wi-Fi. :-)

Comment: CIFS/samba doesn't required internet access, a LAN is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are several [File manager supporting all local file systems & LAN](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman#group_156), so they can access your Windows shares directly – no Internet required, just a local WiFi both, your Android device(s) and Computer(s) are connected to. My (very subjective) "top 3" you can find described [in my answer on our sister-site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/30314/185), together with some screenshots: [ES File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.estrongs.android.pop), [Open Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.brandroid.openmanager) (also see my recommendation [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26657/185)), [Solid Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/pl.solidexplorer). All 3 have network capabilities and even can auto-discover your Windows shares.

Comment: I want to know how can I implement that feautre in my Android App

Comment: Wrong place to ask then. This site is for *end users* of Android, development issues are off-topic here.